# GWT CellTable within TabLayoutPanel: no line wrap of data

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I want to display several `CellTable`s within a `TabLayoutPanel`. Each tab has a single wrapped `CellTable` as it's widget.

My problem is: if I have a table which has many columns, in my case 12, the content flows to the right of the panel, means that some content is not visible. This is not the case if I display the table without a TabLayoutPanel; in that case, there are automatic line breaks so that all columns fit on the screen.

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I do not want to specify absolute widths, neither for the table nor for the columns as I want the table to use 100% of the available screen width.